# method invoked when a gridview records from database are null

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview which uses a stored procedure with session["UserName"] as a parameter to retrieve the records from the database.

Here is the code for that gridview Sqldatasource:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:componentConnString %>"
    SelectCommand="SelectUserPreviousHistory" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="userName" SessionField="UserName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

lets say a particular user who has logged in doesn't have any records in that table on which this particular stored procedure is being executed. Then there won't be any records associated with gridview. So in this scenario: is there any method that gets executed or some exception is thrown, so that i can explicitly use that method/exception/property to display a message Label to the user like "No records to show !!"

please help me

BTW i'm using vs 2008, c#, asp.net
Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greetings 
   Well if i got you right you need to display a text to the user tell them no data found or something

so you can use a property on the grid view called

```
EmptyDataText = "no Data Found !"
```

Set it on the HTML like this for example

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" EmptyDataText="No Data Found !" runat="server" >
        </asp:GridView>
```

Also to set the style of that region of the Empty Data Text Field or div if you play with Visual studio intellsince  you can find such like

```
EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass
```

and others too

Please don't forget to sign this answer is correct if its useful to you :)

Regards :)

Comment: It is displaying with borders how can i remove that ?

Comment: wait i will test :) just a sec i think if you give it a EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass with nothing about border it will remove the border

Comment: well i tried what i said but it seems in firebug the plugin i use to see the dom elements in firefox in runtime that this border is the grid border so i need to see how to remove it in case no data so i will find a solution when i do i will write it down here :)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the Selected event of the SQLDataSource to check the number of records returned.  For example:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) {
    if(e.AffectedRows == 0)
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "startUp", "alert(recordset is empty);", true);
}
```

Comment: what is typeof(Page) ?? What should i write at page ??

Comment: You may use this code as is.  It should be compiled and run properly.  The type and key parameters identify the script block you are registering.  To learn about the ClientStartupScript method, please refer to MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend i found a solution but its a server side one when binding the grid or after exactly binding it do the following

```
//---- just an examply for binding grid with 0 rows [no data found]
    myGridView.DataSource = null; 
    myGridView.DataBind();
//----
myGridView.BorderWidth = ((myGridView.Rows.Count <= 0) ? (new Unit(0)) : (new Unit(1)));
```

Thanks for your waiting :)